# Is there an easy way to include jQuery UI plugins like DataTables in React.JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, datatables

Ideally I would like to create a class in React which will contain a "table" inside it's state.  This table would then be a jQuery datatable.  And then whenever I modify the state of this class, to add or delete a row, the table would react automatically.  Is there an elegant way to do this in React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend an approach from [React training tutorial](https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-training/blob/gh-pages/lessons/05-wrapping-dom-libs.md). It uses integration with Jquery UI Dialog as an example, but it's generally applicable for most 3rd party libraries with React.

Basically you need to implement following steps:

- render plugin in `componentDidMount` with passed `props` as plugin's options
- rerender on getting new `props` in `componentWillReceiveProps`
- cleanup DOM, unsubscribe from events etc. in `componentWillUnmount`

Explore provided link for code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Griddle](http://griddlegriddle.github.io/Griddle)... I think it's exactly what you're looking for.

> Out of the box, Griddle has sorting, filtering, paging, infinite scrolling, sub-grids and more. Even more functionality is on the way!